# My ios app is used for EVERY facebook login? (even instagram,...)

Tags: ios, facebook, redirect, authentication

My iOS app uses facebook login for users. But suddenly if the user is in any other app (Instagram,...) and wanna login there, they will be redirected to my app for facebook login. This is really weird and i've never expierienced something like that - may someone have an idea whats going on here?

Comment: You have specified Facebooks namespace in your app. Don't do that.

Comment: Hi WizKid! Thanks for your answer. What does that exactly mean? "Specified Facebooks namespace" ? sorry for bothering, i dont really get what you mean by that, thanks for your help!

Comment: do you mean in xcode or in facebook app settings?

Comment: xcode. You added fbauth I believe. Saying that your app should handle those app links.

Comment: yes, you're right. so i need to delete all fbauth and fbauth2 entries in plist?

Comment: Correct. They should not be there